# Reference for class instance on a IF condition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game organized in several states, and want to create some GUI components that are exclusive to this states.

The problem I have is to create an IF condition to check the current state.

this is the class:

```
public interface IStateBase  
    {
        void StateUpdate();
        void ShowIt();
    }
}
```

This is where the instance of the class if created and managed:

```
public class StateManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static IStateBase activeState;

    void Start () 
    {
        activeState = new BeginState (this);
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if (activeState != null)
            activeState.StateUpdate();
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (activeState != null)
            activeState.ShowIt();    }

    public void ShowIt()
    {

    }

    public void SwitchState(IStateBase newState)
        {
        activeState = newState;
        }
}
```

And here is where I am testing the condition, I tried to compare strings but it is not working.

```
public class PlayLevel1 : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private HydroElectric ec;
    public static string a;

    public PlayLevel1 ()
    {
        ec = new HydroElectric();
            a =  "PlayState";
    }
    public void OnGUI()
    {
            if (StateManager.activeState.ToString() == a) {

                string test1;

                GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width - 100, 20, 80, 40), test1.ToString ());
                }
     }
```

Do you have any idea how can I code the if condition to check for the activestate value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `PlayState` is a class which implements `IStateBase`, then you can check if `StateManager.activeState` is a `PlayState` instance like so:

```
if (StateManager.activeState is PlayState) { // ...
```

More info on the `is` operator is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Right on the spot! Thanks so much! I was not aware of the "is" comparative!

Comment: You'd be better with a delegate though. This is fine but slower than a basic delegate update and call.